# keyboard is not dismissing if i use modal segue

Tags: ios

I am using simple Modal segues between view controllers and i it is not dismissing the keyboard. I tries [textField resignFirstResponder] on view will disappear method but still no luck.

I am not using any Navigation Controllers, just simple View Controllers.

I also tried doing this but still no luck. Need Help.

View Controller A ---------> View Controller B

in View controller B. I called [self disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal] in viewDidLoad.

and I've overridden in it like so

```
    -(BOOl)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
    {
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with `r`?

Comment: my bad. didn't realize it.BTW i ended up changing the text field to a button which totally did the trick

Comment: Phew, I was going to lose sleep over this one!

Answer (score 0):

This one could help you too

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

With this, when you tap outside the textfield , the keyboard disappear